# Switching between split buffers in vim

Tags: vim, buffer

recently starting trying to use VIM as my full-time text editor since I spent a lot of time SSH'ed anyways. Recently installed NERDTree so I can quickly swap between files in a project.

Easy question that I can't seem to find on Google (perhaps not using the right terminology) - how do I easily switch focus between the two buffers when using NERDTree? Meaning how can I go from browsing the directory on the left to browsing the file on the right easily?

Thanks.

Answer (score 11):

<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd><kbd>w</kbd> - switch between buffers

instead of last <kbd>w</kbd> you can use any of <kbd>←</kbd> <kbd>↑</kbd> <kbd>↓</kbd> <kbd>→</kbd>.

Comment: Or hjkl instead of arrows :)